# Mysql duplicate row prevention

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, insert

[image]

this is my event_attended table,i have two more tables : users and events , i am importing data from csv file,from the csv file it is taking the username and event name then it is inserting the user_id and event_id in the event_attended table.

i don't want the same row values to be inserted in the table.
for example: 1st row has user_id = 73 and event_id = 16 , so table should not have the same values again but it can have the same user_id again with the different event_id.
for example: 4th row user_id = 73 and event_id = 18.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to see how to add a unique constraint to your table.  This is probably the easiest/best way to enforce your requirement.

Comment: Have you done some research? After a few minutes you should find the MySQL Documentation Entry for **unique constraints**

Comment: As there's a unique value, may as well make it the PK and leave off id.

Comment: but if i add unique constraints to both the columns then i will not be able to use the same values again like the 4th row in my table. right? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: No...add the unique constraint on _both_ columns, `user_id` and `event_id`.  Then, only a given combination of those two values can appear only once.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much . i will try that :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i added the unique constraint to both the columns and then i insert the following data:
INSERT INTO `attended`(`user_id`, `event_id`) VALUES ('73','16')
it got inserted.
INSERT INTO `attended`(`user_id`, `event_id`) VALUES ('73','18')
i am not able to insert this 
error: Duplicate entry '73' for key 'user_id_2
@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `ALTER TABLE attended ADD CONSTRAINT constr_ID UNIQUE (user_id, event_id)` ... _Also_, if you have any other unique constraints on the individual columns `user_id` or `event_id`, then you'll need to remove those.

Comment: Worked :) Thanks again :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Yes i removed that :D